# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.The response had HTTP status code 401

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, tomcat

I am calling a cross doamin REST web-service(Spring) using angular $http. Please find code below.

```
$http({    
url: ' http://xxx.yyy.zzz:8080/..../sponsors',
method: 'GET',
   headers: {  'Token' : 'abc'  }
}).success(function(sponsors){
      $scope.sponsorList = sponsors;
}).error(function(sponsors){
       alert('failed to get sponsors')
});
```

I am getting the below error

**"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."**

Restful webservices are deployed on Tomcat-8.

I have added a CORS filter in tomcat/conf/web.xml as below.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Even though i am getting the same error .

Can anybody please help me how to fix this? Did i miss any headers at client side? Anything else needs to be done at server side?

Thanks in advance

Comment: any chance that your app is cached and your attempted addition in `web.xml` have not applied? (you can force clean the `webapps` dir by deleting it's content, redeploy your app and restart tomcat)

Comment: I have restarted tomcat multiple times.

Comment: can you show us filter section of web.xml ?

Comment: <filter>
          <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
         <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
         <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping>

Answer (score 1):

This would help you based on this [link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html)

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>10</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I have tried this more advanced configuration also.but no luck:(

Comment: have you tried cors.allowed.headers ? it will not support * if you put there *

Comment: I have tried exactly what you have given above. referred this  https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause.

I have created simple hello world REST service without authentication on the same server and called the service.

I got the response without any issues.

I am getting the below error with existing production application which has authentication
**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.The response had HTTP status code 401**

So i concluded that authentication is needed for PREFLIGHT request also.

Can anybody tell me how to send  authentication headers in PREFLIGHT request?
Do we have control on PREFLIGHT Requests?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this flow chart could help you to understand what happens: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/images/cors-flowchart.png.

Could you give us the content of the `OPTIONS` request sent (both request and response content)? You can have access to this from the Network tabs of the Chrome dev tools...